# How do I query multiple rows in node-orm2?

Tags: node-orm2

From the manual I understand the following instruction...

```
Person.find({ name: "Jack" }, function (err, people) {
// finds people with name='Jack'
});
```

I would like to find two people, "Jack" and "Jill". This is obviously incorrect, but something like...

```
Person.find({ name: "Jack" AND name: "Jill" }, function (err, people) {
// finds all people with name='Jack' and name ='Jill' 
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/wiki/Finding-items#conditions-for-findcountone-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Person.find({or:[{name: 'Jack'}, {name: 'Jill'}]}, function(err, res) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
Person.find({ name: ["Jack", "Jill"] }, function (err, people) {
    // finds all people with name='Jack' and name ='Jill' 
});
```